# Importing Maven Project in Windows 7

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin

I have copied maven project into my pendrive from ubuntu machine and import in STS IDE in Windows 7.
But in STS Maven Dependencies are not coming and that's why project is not running.It's also showing error ----> "you are using other project's pom".What should i do to get rid of this problem.

Comment: mine work, can you provide more information to diagnostic it

Comment: Maven is Java and Java is not bound to a specific version of a specific platform. You are doing something else wrong. You may want to begin by taking that error you are getting seriously; try a google search on it to see what others had to say about it.

Comment: Jar files of Maven Dependency are showing in STS IDE in Ubuntu but it's not showing in Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try outside of STS first.

Make sure Maven is installed and its */bin* path is in `PATH` env. variable.

Through console, go to the root of project(where `pom.xml` is), run `mvn clean install`

See if maven is downloading dependencies, if not check your Maven configuration & internet.

If this works, then try in STS. If in STS doesn't work, try to update its maven plugin, or do a complete reinstall